# Left outer join with only first row

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

I have a query something like

```
SELECT S.product_id, S.link, C.id AS category_id
FROM Products P
INNER JOIN SEO S ON S.product_id = P.id AND P.product_type = 1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Categories C ON c.product_id = P.id
WHERE P.active = 1
```

I works fine for me as long as each product has assigned to only one category. But if a product is assigned to many categories it returns all possible combinations.

Can I only select the first one and if a product don't have any category the link should still be returned with category_id = NULL

Comment: `The first one`, according to what criteria?

Comment: You could add a MIN or MAX and GROUP BY on category_id. If that's not good enough, move Categories into a subquery.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An easy way is to use outer apply, so as to have a correlated join, and make that a top 1 query. Thus you are able to access all columns of the category record in question. I'm adding a category name here as an example:

```
select s.product_id, s.link, c.id as category_id, c.name as category_name
from products p
inner join seo s on s.product_id = p.id 
outer apply
(
  select top 1 * 
  from categories cat
  where cat.product_id = p.id
  order by cat.id
) c
where p.active = 1
and p.product_type = 1;
```

Comment: By using Outer apply it is also possible to order by any column on the category table which is probably what he  needs.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a [GROUP BY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx) to accomplish this along with an [Aggregate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx) function, most likely [MIN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179916.aspx) or [MAX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187751.aspx).

Depending on which Category Id you prefer in your result you could select the minimum.

```
SELECT S.product_id, S.link, MIN(C.id) AS category_id
FROM Products P
INNER JOIN SEO S ON S.product_id = P.id AND P.product_type = 1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Categories C ON c.product_id = P.id
WHERE P.active = 1
GROUP BY S.product_id, S.link
```

Or the maximum.

```
SELECT S.product_id, S.link, MAX(C.id) AS category_id
FROM Products P
INNER JOIN SEO S ON S.product_id = P.id AND P.product_type = 1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Categories C ON c.product_id = P.id
WHERE P.active = 1
GROUP BY S.product_id, S.link
```

Comment: Wouldn't this return multiple rows? The MAX/MIN function is applied to the result set, it does not filter the rows in the result set...

Comment: @JustinRowe The `GROUP BY` limits you to one row per `product_id` and `link` combination.

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution becomes more complex as soon as you want to retrieve more than one column beside the group-by columns.

Answer (score 1):

Alternate solution using subquery:

```
SELECT S.product_id, S.link, 
(
 SELECT C.id FROM Categories C WHERE C.product_id = P.id AND
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY /* your sort option goes here*/ ) = 1
) AS category_id
FROM Products P
INNER JOIN SEO S ON S.product_id = P.id AND P.product_type = 1
WHERE P.active = 1
```